# Exporting extern variables from dll visual C++

Tags: c++, dll, c++20, dllexport

Basically I have a dll project in visual studio. I'm linking this dll project to a second project successfully but as soon as I try to use extern variables things go wrong. I've seperated my extern variables into a single header and source file from everything else so I can isolate the problem and potential solutions. I've scowered the internet for hours now and I feel like I've tried everything. I am beginning to think it might be a compile flag? Anyway, heres my code.

macros.h

```
#pragma once    

// dll management
#ifdef TOAST_EXPORT
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define TAPI __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define TAPI __attribute__((visibility("default")))
#endif
#else
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define TAPI __declspec(dllimport)
#else
#define TAPI
#endif
#endif
```

globals.h

```
#pragma once

#define TOAST_EXPORT
#include "macros.h"

namespace toast
{
    TAPI extern const char c;
}
```

globals.c

*Note that I tried this without const and made no assignment here*

```
#pragma once
#include "globals.h"

namespace toast
{
    const char c = 'a';
}
```

main.c (from the project that compiles to an exe)

```
#include <globals.h>

int main()
{
    char c = toast::c;
    return 0;
}
```

So far I've tried making a lot of subtle changes like reordering extern and const and such. I've also done it both with just extern and just const. Still produces the same `unresolved external symbol "char const toast::c"` error. Keep in mind that I can create instances of classes and call their methods from the dll successfully and thats with things like `class TAPI logger...` and such.

Comment: @AlexF that is just an alternative to defining `TOAST_EXPORT` before including `macros.h`. Both achieve the same thing.

Comment: `globals.c` does not include `globals.h` therefore export declarations have no effect. It includes `io.h` which is not present in question at all.

Comment: #define TOAST_EXPORT in globals.h makes little sense, that file needs to be included as well in the .exe project to get the variable declaration and it doesn't export that variable.  You'd normally set it in the .dll project properties, add it to the Project > Properties > C/C++ > Preprocessor, "Preprocessor definitions" setting.

Comment: Hans Passant, i originally didn't do the pre-processor because I intended to also compile with gcc. I thought it would be easier to just make a header. However this is kinda irrelevant and you're criticising something that looks pretty standard for anything but visual studio projects.

Comment: You need to not define `TOAST_EXPORT` when using the `dll` otherwise you will be trying to export from the `exe` instead of importing from the dll.

Comment: user78606670 that was a typo in the question but not in my project. Thanks for pointing that out. I have the files called io currently since that's what the externs were for but in simplifying it I thought global's would make better sense in the question.

Comment: descherjm, you're right, I thought I'd tried that but I must've done something else wrong when I did. Once I got rid of const, not defining `TOAST_EXPORT` fixed it. Thanks for the help.